# Why i can not load a simple pixel shader effect (. fx) file in xna?

Tags: xna, shaders, fragment-shader

I just want to load a simple *.fx file into my project to make a (pixel shader) effect.

But whenever I try to compile my project, I get the following error in visual studio Error List:

```
Errors compiling ..
ID3DXEffectCompiler: There were no techniques
ID3DXEffectCompiler: Compilation failed
```

I already searched on google and found many people with the same problem. And I realized that it was a problem of encoding. With the return lines unrecognized '\ n' .

I tried to copy and paste to notepad and save as with ASCII or UTF8 encoding. But the result is always the same.

Do you have an idea please ? Thanks a looot :-)

Here is my [.fx] file :

```
sampler BaseTexture : register(s0);
sampler MaskTexture : register(s1) 
{
    addressU = Clamp;
    addressV = Clamp;
};

//All of these variables are pixel values
//Feel free to replace with float2 variables
float MaskLocationX;
float MaskLocationY;
float MaskWidth;
float MaskHeight;
float BaseTextureLocationX;  //This is where your texture is to be drawn
float BaseTextureLocationY;  //texCoord is different, it is the current pixel
float BaseTextureWidth;
float BaseTextureHeight;


float4 main(float2 texCoord : TEXCOORD0) : COLOR0
{
    //We need to calculate where in terms of percentage to sample from the MaskTexture
    float maskPixelX = texCoord.x * BaseTextureWidth + BaseTextureLocationX;
    float maskPixelY = texCoord.y * BaseTextureHeight + BaseTextureLocationY;
    float2 maskCoord = float2((maskPixelX - MaskLocationX) / MaskWidth, (maskPixelY - MaskLocationY) / MaskHeight);
    float4 bitMask = tex2D(MaskTexture, maskCoord);

    float4 tex = tex2D(BaseTexture, texCoord);

    //It is a good idea to avoid conditional statements in a pixel shader if you can use math instead.
    return tex * (bitMask.a);
    //Alternate calculation to invert the mask, you could make this a parameter too if you wanted
    //return tex * (1.0 - bitMask.a);
}
```

Comment: I'd say your problem is perfectly explained by the error message. There are no techniques in your file. You just have a pixel shader. How about adding a vertex shader, and a technique to bind them together? Check [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb206368(v=vs.85).aspx) for more information.

Comment: Yes it was exactly that !! thank you so much it's work fine , Do you can put this on a answer please ? So i can close this post directly after

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say your problem is perfectly explained by the error message. There are no techniques in your file. You just have a pixel shader.

An effect contains one or more techniques, each one described by one or more passes, each one implemented by a vertex shader and a pixel shader.

Your file only contains a pixel shader, and that's what the compiler is complaining about. If you use an effect file, you should have at least one pixel shader, one vertex shader, and a technique with at least one pass that makes use of your shaders.

You can find more information on how to write an effects file at the [official documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb206368%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).